# why HTML sub menu in a wrong postion?

Tags: html, css, menu

I a have HTML,CSS menu.

I want sub menu center to the main menu(ul.menu)

why there are a space on the left?

**ul.menu li:hover ul** already defined the **left: 0** and his nearest parents is **ul.menu**, don't understand where these space come from?

[image]

```css
.menu-main-container { padding-bottom:52px; margin-top:-60px; margin:10px auto; }
ul.menu { z-index: 597; text-align:center; position: relative;background: gray; width: 960px; margin:auto!important;}
ul.menu li { display: inline-block; line-height: 2.1em; vertical-align: middle; zoom: 1; }
ul.menu a { display:block;  letter-spacing:2px; color:#333; font-size:13px; text-decoration: none; padding:0 35px; text-transform:uppercase; font-weight:normal !important;}
ul.menu a:hover {background:#EFEFEF; color:#ad7f12}
ul.menu, ul.menu li, ul.menu ul { list-style: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; color:#333; }

ul.menu li:hover { position: relative; z-index:599; text-decoration:none; background:#EFEFEF; }
ul.menu li:hover ul {}
ul.menu ul { display: none; }
ul.menu ul li { float: none; line-height:34px; margin:0; padding:0; display: inline-block;}
ul.menu ul li a:hover{ }
ul.menu ul li { top: -2px; left: 100%; }
ul.menu li:hover ul { display:inline-block; position: absolute; top: 100%; left: 0; z-index: 598; width:1020px; background:red; }
```

```html
<div class="" ="menu-main-container">

<ul class="menu">
<li><a href="#">Menu 1</a>
 <ul>
 <li><a href="#">Menu 1 Submenu item 1</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Menu 1 Submenu item 2</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Menu 1 Submenu item 3</a></li>
 </ul>
</li>

<li><a href="#">Menu 2</a>
 <ul>
 <li><a href="#">Menu 2 Submenu item 1</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Menu 2 Submenu item 2</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Menu 2 Submenu item 3</a></li>
 </ul>
</li>

<li><a href="#">Menu 3</a>
 <ul>
 <li><a href="#">Menu 3 Submenu item 1</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Menu 3 Submenu item 2</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Menu 3 Submenu item 3</a></li>
 </ul>
</li> 
</ul>

</div>
```

Comment: Can you add a picture describing what do you want to achieve? Are you trying to center the red sub-menu relative to the grey main menu?

Comment: Actually, you are setting `left: 100%` here: `ul.menu ul li { top: -2px; left: 100%; }`, try to get rid of it

Comment: Thanks. I delete "left: 100%" still doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is starting from that whitespace because it is positioning from it's parent. Remove this:

```
position: relative;
```

Comment: Cool, don't know why but fixed. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

The nearest parent is not ul.menu, but ul.menu li.  This is why it's not centered.  It is basing it's position off of ul.menu li.  Changing the parent element will not work either, you will have to use another method in conjunction with css for that to work.  jQuery or Javascript are the best solutions here, in my opinion.

Comment: Sorry I didn't make clear. I mean The nearest positioned parent. As I know   sub menu (**ul.menu li:hover ul** ) position should relative to it's nearest positioned parent which is **ul.menu**

Comment: Right, but in this case it's all dependent of the parent element.  It won't take the positioned parent two layers up.  That's just not how it works, it will take the position of the immediate parent.

Comment: Actually, see the answer below.  I tested that and it seems to accomplish what you need.

Comment: Thank you for explaining it to me .